# Convert Xml String with node prefixes to XElement

Tags: xml-parsing, xelement

This is my xml string

```
 string fromHeader= "<a:From><a:Address>http://ex1.example.org/</a:Address></a:From>";
```

I want to load it into an XElement, but doing XElement.Parse(fromHeader) gives me an error due to the 'a' prefixes. I tried the following:

```
XNamespace xNSa = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
string dummyRoot = "<root xmlns:a=\"{0}\">{1}</root>";
var fromXmlStr = string.Format(dummyRoot, xNSa, fromHeader);
XElement xFrom = XElement.Parse(fromXmlStr).Elements().First();
```

which works, but seriously, do i need 4 lines of code to do this! What is a quickest / shortest way of getting my XElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the above 4 lines are equivalent to

```
XNamespace xNSa = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
XElement xFrom =  new XElement(xNSa + "From", new XElement(xNSa + "Address", "http://ex1.example.org/"));
```

OR ALTERNATIVELY move the NS into the 'From' element before parsing.

```
var fromStr = "<a:From xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><a:Address>http://ex1.example.org/</a:Address></a:From>";
XElement xFrom = XElement.Parse(fromStr);
```